# IF OR Syntax in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I need help adding some logic to my syntax. Current formula is set to the following value and it works perfectly:

```
=IF(AAA<>"","Closed",IF([BBB]<>"","Pending Approval","Pending Review"))
```

I would like to add some OR logic to this part ([BBB]<>""OR"ZZZ", and essentially want the formula to perform this:

```
=IF(AAA<>"","Closed",IF([BBB]<>""OR"ZZZ","Pending Approval","Pending Review"))
```

this doesn't work either:

```
=IF(AAA<>"","Closed",IF(OR(ISBLANK([BBB]),"Pending Approval"),"Pending Review"),(OR([BBB])<>"ZZZ","Pending Approval","Pending Review")
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use below:

```
=IF(AAA<>"","Closed",IF(OR(BBB<>"",BBB="ZZZ"),"Pending Approval","Pending Review"))
```

[image]